# DHCP Option not working

Tags: dhcp, options

I'm using Debian with a DHCP server. I want my SIP Phone to get another VLAN and some more options, so I set the following configuration:

```
option space OptiIpPhone code width 1 length width 1 hash size 3;
option OptiIpPhone.code1forvendor code 1 = text;
option OptiIpPhone.code2forvlan code 2 = text;
option OptiIpPhone.code3fordls code 3 = text;

subnet 172.16.12.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 172.16.12.20 172.16.12.254;
  default-lease-time 3600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
  option routers 172.16.12.1;
  option domain-name-servers 172.16.12.1;
  vendor-option-space OptiIpPhone;
  option OptiIpPhone.code1forvendor "Siemens";
  option OptiIpPhone.code2forvlan "5";
  option OptiIpPhone.code3fordls "sdlp://172.16.5.50:18443";


  option ntp-servers 172.16.12.1;



  use-host-decl-names on;
  authoritative;
  ping-check true;

}
```

If I am using the `Class` and `Subclass` Method it works totally fine, but in the subnet its not working.

Comment: `Debian with a DHCP server` does this mean your Debian system has *a DHCP server* (which one?) and it's the ONLY dhcp server on your network?